# Android horizontal design

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make horizontally design that divides screen into 4x 50% pieces within scrollable view.

I'm having linear layout that divides the screen into two 50% parts. That's okay. How to add another two 50% "under the screen" - note this root linear layout in enclosed within scroll view...

This is what I want to achieve: http://s7.postimg.org/9qyy3y1h7/image.jpg

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/as_30d"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:background="#dddddd"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Your activity - kilometers"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chart"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/as_30d"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#dddddd"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Your activity - kilometers"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chart"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas will are appreciated. I am able to figure out it myself if you give my some tips :) Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe what is the result you want to achieve from user-experience point of view? At least for me the sentence `horizontally design that divides screen into 4x 50% pieces within scrollable view` is confusing. The scrolling will appear if you have a `ScrollView`/`HorizontalScrollView` **AND** the content is wider than the viewport. You can implement the scrolling for yourself, but I am sure you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I need to achieve this exactly:

http://s7.postimg.org/9qyy3y1h7/image.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that what you want is possible just within the XML.

A solution is to at runtime get the screen height and set the height of the two nested LinearLayouts to that.

Alternatively you can use a vertical ViewPager implementation with separate fragments if that suits your needs.

Comment: Oh thank you very much kmg. I've programatically set it to 50% and its working just like a charm. Thanks.

I am already using tabs so using ViewPager doesn't seem user-friendly for me.